# What is happening on this third example?

Tags: c++

Consider:

1.

```
int one=1;
void func(int* ptr)
{
  ptr=&one;
}

int main() {
int nvar=2;
int* pvar=&nvar;
func(pvar);
std::cout<<*pvar<<std::endl;
return0
};
```

Will still output 2 because a copy of pvar is created right?

2.

```
void func(int*& ptr)
{
  ptr=&one;
}
```

Output will be 1 because a reference of the pointer has been passed, all good

3.

```
int one=1;
void func(int** ptr)
{
  *ptr=&one;
//or **ptr=one;
}
int main()
{
    int nvar=2;
    int* pvar=&nvar;
    func(&pvar);
    std::cout<<*pvar<<std::endl;
```

Outputs 1

I couldn't elaborate a more appropriate question title because I honestly don't know **what** third example is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third example is very similar to the second because you still pass the pointer to your pvar pointer. Pointer to pointer means you can change whatever your pointer points to.

The main difference between pointer to pointer (**) and pointer reference (*&) is that whenever you pass a pointer reference, then your pointer has to be initialised (non-null, has a well-defined value).

Comment: +1 for mentioning that references should never be (and if you're not doing something obviously stupid), can never be null.

Answer (score 2):

The third example creates a pointer to the local variable `nvar`, containing `2`, passess pointer to this pointer to the `func`, where it is overwritten by pointer to the global `one`, containing one. Then it prints the value pointed to by `pvar`, which is `one`, which is `1`. (in case of `// or **ptr=one`, it puts the `one` value into the variable pointed to by the pointer, which is `nvar`, still ending up with the same output).